# A bit of `padding-bottom` for `.deleted-answer` would be better

Tags: discussion, bug, design, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Currently, the `.deleted-answer` div has no [`padding-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom), looks kind of broken:

[image]